# merge json data uniquely in php

Tags: php, json, unique, array-merge

I want to merge json data uniquely. I have two json data, need one resulted json data that contains both json data in unique way.

```
$json1 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A2","phone":"456"}]';
$json2 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A3","phone":"789"}]';

$decoded_json1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$decoded_json2 = json_decode($json2, true);

var_dump($decoded_json1);
var_dump($decoded_json2);

$merge_json = array_merge($decoded_json1, $decoded_json2);

var_dump($merge_json);

/* I want json data like this
[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A2","phone":"456"}, {"name":"A3","phone":"789"}]
 */
```

But the above code is not working fine it merge the json data but problem is that it's not a unique this object `{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}` repeat.

**UPDATE:**

```
  $json2 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A3","phone":"789"}, {"name":"A1","phone":"000"}]';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Updated:**

```
$json1 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A2","phone":"456"}]';
$json2 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A3","phone":"789"},    {"name":"A1","phone":"000"}]';
$array = array_unique(array_merge(json_decode($json1, true), json_decode($json2, true)), SORT_REGULAR);

function data_uniquely($key, $array) {
   $_array = array();
   foreach ($array as $v) {
      if (isset($_array[$v[$key]]))
         continue;
      $_array[$v[$key]] = $v;
   }
   $array = array_values($_array);
   return json_encode($array);
}
$json = data_uniquely('name', $array);
echo $json;
```

Json result:

```
[
 {
   "name": "A1",
   "phone": "123"
 },
 {
   "name": "A2",
   "phone": "456"
 },
 {
   "name": "A3",
   "phone": "789"
 }
]
```

Comment: This is not working for all kind of json data check the update in my question this is not working for that json

Comment: @PakDeveloper , take a look to the post again, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't going to know what's unique and what isn't, you're going to need to manually do this.

> code

```
<?php

$json1 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A2","phone":"456"}]';
$json2 = '[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}, {"name":"A3","phone":"789"}]';

$decoded_json1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$decoded_json2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$newArray = [];

foreach($decoded_json1 as $row) {
    $hash = hash('SHA256', json_encode($row));
    $newArray[$hash] = $row;
}

foreach($decoded_json2 as $row) {
    $hash = hash('SHA256', json_encode($row));
    $newArray[$hash] = $row;
}

// remove the hash keys
$newArray = array_values($newArray);

var_dump($newArray);
```

> output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "A1"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "A2"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(3) "456"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "A3"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(3) "789"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for all kind of json data check the update in my question this is not working for that json

Comment: So what is it that needs to be unique? just the name?

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() only filter duplicated key members, so you can use `json_encode()`, `json_decode()` and `array_unique()` to do:

```
$tmp = array_map('json_encode', $merge_json); // Encode everyone array members.
$tmp = array_unique($tmp); // Filter duplicated
$tmp = array_values($tmp); // Re generate array indexes
$tmp = json_encode($tmp);
echo $tmp;
```

Result:

```
[{"name":"A1","phone":"123"}","{"name":"A2","phone":"456"}","{"name":"A3","phone":"789"}]
```